# C# datagridview query variable

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm building a c# application to display data from my database into a datagridview. Each user logged in in the first window. Then the user can register his data or can see his already registered data.

But if the user logged in, he have a userid. How can I display only the data correspondeni with the user id?

I have currently this, but it doesn't work. I see all the data from all users.

```
SELECT Id, gebruikerid, datum, afstand, tijd FROM prestaties
WHERE gebruikerid = '" + label1.Text + "'
```

The value of the userid stays in label1. This value is a variable

With entering the query in the query builder from the datagridview wizard, I get the error that the query not correct is.

Comment: try to avoid writing inline queries,bad practice of programming

Answer (score 0):

Even though this post is from 2 years ago I would give you my answer anyways.

Make an SQL parameter using `@` in your query:

```
SELECT Id, gebruikerid, datum, afstand, tijd FROM prestaties
WHERE gebruikerid = @userid
```

Then right click on the "FillBy" button and choose "View Code":

[image]

You will then see this event handler:

```
private void fillBy1ToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.yourSqlAdapter.FillBy1(this.yourDatabaseDataSet.prestaties, ((int)(System.Convert.ChangeType(testToolStripTextBox.Text, typeof(int)))));
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Now, replace `testToolStripTextBox.Text` with your `label1.Text` and the value from your `label1.Text` will be used as parameter in your SQL query.